# Nextcloud cron.php timings

Tags: php, cron, timeout, owncloud, nextcloud

As [recommended by Nextcloud Official Documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/11/admin_manual/configuration_server/background_jobs_configuration.html#cron), I started to use a system that calls the `cron.php` every 15 minutes. The call is wrapped in a program that reports errors to me via e-mail and enforces a timeout of 2 minutes on the execution of the `cron.php`.

Sometimes that the timeout is reached, the wrapper sends **SIGTERM** and the `cron.php` exits peacefully - without need for SIGKILL.

It doesn't print anything - not also to the Apache `error.log` - while doing so. Whenever I check the admin interface, it reports the Cron has been executed recently. The problem occurs roughly once per week.

BTW, I've already had this before switching to Nextcloud.

Is the timeout of two minutes just too low? Or is it a bug? What should I do?

Comment: The Nextcloud Cron job also triggers actions defined by various apps (e.g. the News app fetches RSS / Atoms feeds, the trash bin / versioned files get cleaned etc.). What additional apps do have installed? How many users and/or files do you have? On what hardware are your running your installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried activating the DEBUG level in the logs for some time? Please have a look at
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/admin_manual/configuration_server/logging_configuration.html#log-level
and set the level to 0.

Then you should see the cron tab describing its action, and you can time the various jobs. Here is an excerpt of a log (from NC version 9 because I did not have to perform such an analysis since migrating to 13, but format should be similar).

> {"reqId":"6wulvcxV3RGWrlto+5V0","remoteAddr":"","app":"cron","message":"Run
>   OCA\User_LDAP\Jobs\CleanUp job with ID
>   16","level":0,"time":"2018-11-08T21:30:02+00:00","method":"--","url":"--","user":"--","version":"9.1.5.2"}
>   {"reqId":"6wulvcxV3RGWrlto+5V0","remoteAddr":"","app":"cron","message":"Finished
>   OCA\User_LDAP\Jobs\CleanUp job with ID
>   16","level":0,"time":"2018-11-08T21:30:02+00:00","method":"--","url":"--","user":"--","version":"9.1.5.2"}

You can filter the messages with the "app":"cron" value, and separate the requests with the "reqId", then time the duration of a job between the "Run" and the "Finished".

As a final remark, my NC instance goes by the GB, and cron jobs can last way more than 2 minutes. Some of the apps (retention) seriously need SQL optimisation also, otherwise the jobs will last for ages.

cheers, hj